# VSCode doesn't recognize ConfluentKafkaLibrary to use in Robot Framework

Tags: python, apache-kafka, robotframework, confluent-kafka-python

I need to do a test automation in Robot Framework using Kafka topics. I'm trying to use the ConfluentKafkaLibrary library, but VSCode doesn't recognize it.

I already installed the commands:

```
pip install robotframework-confluentkafkalibrary
pip install confluent-kafka
```

Still, it keeps giving the error:

> `Unresolved library: ConfluentKafkaLibrary. Error generating libspec: Importing library 'ConfluentKafkaLibrary' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_bz2' Consider adding the needed paths to the "robot.pythonpath" setting and calling the "Robot Framework: Clear caches and restart" action.`

**Does anyone know how to solve this problem?**

[IMAGE - error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T49v5.jpg)

- I already tried to reinstall all libraries.
- I already tried to configure the robot.pythonpath.
- I've restarted VSCode several times, after each step.

Comment: It's complaining about the `_bz2.pyd` dynamic library.  That's installed as part of the Python standard library.  Have you messed with your Python paths?

Comment: I had just edit the "robot.pythonpath" on the file settings.json:

{
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "redhat.telemetry.enabled": true,
    "python.venvFolders": [
        "/home/mtuser/YIELD/yield-transaction"
    ],
    "robot.pythonpath": [
        "/home/mtuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/"
    ]
}

Comment: If you do `import sys` / `print(sys.path)`, what do you get?

Comment: Thanks for replying Tim. But where should I input these commands? In the Ubuntu terminal?

Comment: You need to know what that version of Python is doing, so put them in your Python file and run it.

Comment: Is the error specific to VSCode? Do you get the same running the file directly?

Comment: I'm trying to use this library in test automation with Robot Framework. So, I still don't know how to run the file without at least applying and testing your keywords.